# Spring Boot project using only AWS free tier

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

AWS has a list of free tier (non-expiring offers) [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/). I wonder if it is enough to deploy a small(less than 1 Gb in total) Spring Boot(+ mongo/postgres) hobby project using ONLY these features.

Comment: you can use it as long as it is within free tier limit. If you happen to use any other service, then they will charge. It depends on what services you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do so, but free tier for EC2 instances that you need to run spring boot application (and mongo/postgres that you install manually on that instance) does expire after 12 months.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can deploy your project on AWS infrastructure in free tier with above requirement.

- For hosting the application you can use **EC2**
- For relational db you can use **RDS** service with **postgres**.
- AWS URLs are very big and complex. So to access your application from AWS infrastructure, You need to use Route 53 service to map it some nice domain name.

Note: If you want to do it for development purpose only, then you can skip the route 53 part.